# Bootstrap - Icon toggle with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I got a little problem trying to toggle an icon of Bootstrap. When i run code it does what expected the first time you click on the icon it toggle's, but when i click again it doesn't change. Here its my code and any help will be appreciated!

```
<a><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>

<script>
  $(".icon-minus").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("icon-minus").addClass("icon-plus");
  });
  $(".icon-plus").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("icon-plus").addClass("icon-minus");
  });
</script>
```

**Update 1:**

This icon is for a collapsible menu and the code of that can be found [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ujonij/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$(".icon-minus, .icon-plus").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("icon-minus icon-plus");
});
```

**Or this if you dynamically create your elements:**

```
$("#parent_el_NOT_dyn_gen").on('click','.icon-minus, .icon-plus',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("icon-minus icon-plus");
});
```

Comment: `toggleClass` takes space-delimited class names, not comma delimited

Comment: @jackwanders and who comma delimited it?

Comment: Its works! But how can i remove the bubbled? Because i use it for display an collapse menu, and if the user click multiple times suddenly i have the minus icon and my collapse menu is hidden. Any suggestions? :) Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeNajeraT sure, but than I need to see your jQuery code that does the animations

Comment: Im using the Boostrap framework so you can find the code in the update that i did on the post! Thanks in advance

Comment: @JorgeNajeraT please create a http://jsFiddle.net or a http://jsBin.com with the issue

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery's selector selects DOM elements then applys the click handler to them. It's not re-evaluating the selector after you change the classes on the element.

You probably want the [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) / [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method from jQuery to dynamically change the the handler that's fired when the item is clicked. Delegate works with event bubbling and will handle the click and evaluate if the source of the click matches the selector (at the time of the click) as opposed to the `.click()` which attaches the handler directly, once (at the time of page-load or whenever the code was ran).

Another solution is to change the handler somehow, either by evaluating what class is on the existing element or using `toggleClass()` which will check for a class then invert it.

```
$(".icon-minus, .icon-plus").click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.hasClass("icon-plus")) {
      $this.removeClass("icon-plus").addClass("icon-minus");
      return;
   }
   if ($this.hasClass("icon-minus")) {
      $this.removeClass("icon-minus").addClass("icon-plus");
      return;
   }
});
```

This method will be slightly faster than using `on()` / `delegate()` because it's handled at the root handler and not bubbled & checked afterwards. It's also not susceptible to any breaks in the event bubbling. (ie. `event.stopPropagation()`)

Comment: Thanks for your response! But i found a bug on your code, when you click the first time it will evaluate the first condition and change the class to icon-minus but because of that it will evaluate the second condition too and change it again to plus!

Comment: Oh you're right, there should be a return in each if block, it's early on a monday and I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution worked for Bootstrap 3.

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).find('.icon-minus-sign, .icon-plus-sign').toggleClass("icon-minus-sign icon-plus-sign");
});
```